# snapd slows down computer

Tags: 18.04, snap

Today i noticed my computer was slowing down, making a lot of noises and other programs would lag. I found out snapd was using 12% cpu on average. It stopped again after a while and I wanted to know what it did so i typed `snap changes` and this comes up:

```
ID   Status  Spawn                Ready                Summary
64   Done    today at 17:03 CEST  today at 17:21 CEST  Auto-refresh snap "gnome-calculator"
```

does this mean snapd took 19 minutes to update a calculator and this process slowed down my computer?

Comment: Slowing down and making a lot of noises seems more like a disk/swap issue. CPUs tend to be silent, and 12% shouldn't make a huge difference in fan noise. Next time you encounter lag, check `free` to see if you are swapping.